# Without Wildcarded Generic Class Parameter Type Lost In ObservableSet forEach

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand the following, and why it might be so:

I have a class:

```
public abstract class ProducerType<T extends BulkItem> extends SomeClass<T> {
    public ObservableSet<ProductType> getProductTypes() {
        return productTypes;
    }
}
```

In another class I have a method:

```
private void buildChildActivities(ProducerType<?> type) {
    type.getProductTypes().forEach((ProductType pt) -> {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

I was initially missing the `<?>` on the `ProducerType` parameter to this method, so it was:

```
private void buildChildActivities(ProducerType type) {
```

which resulted in the type of the members returned in the forEach going missing in the lambda Consumer. The `<T>` generic has no effect on the method defined in `ProducerType` or the Set it returns, so I'm wondering why it fails without the wildcard there?

Comment: What is the purpose of the type variable `T` in the first place (the producer type class)? I can't see any usages.

Comment: `T` is used further up the hierarchy in `SomeClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using generics you are allowed to *opt out* by not providing a type argument. This is then called a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8).

The clue now is: By opting out the generics world in a method's signature, this method uses raw types at all. That means that the method `type.getProductTypes()` now returns a raw `ObservableSet` inside your `buildChildActivities` method. This set type now obviously does not contain any type information, so the compiler must assume `Object`.